# Problem with scipy installation for Sverchok

Tags: python, add-on, sverchok

I'm trying some voronoi with Sverchok and I've see a videa that referes to 3D voronoi node but i found that to run it i need scipy installed.
I've tryied to install it from sverchok from comand line and from anaconda but I cant made it work.
I have blender 2.92 and I use Win 10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751469/blender-trying-to-install-sverchok-addon-scipy-package-but-pip-is-out-of-date?noredirect=1#comment118112911_66751469